# Evernote php - get notes from linked notebook

Tags: php, evernote

I am using this SDK - `https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php`

I can find notes in the my own notebooks, something like this:

```
$client = new \Evernote\Client($token, false);

$search = new \Evernote\Model\Search('*');

$notebook = $client->getNotebook('notebook_id');

$scope = \Evernote\Client::SEARCH_SCOPE_ALL;

$order = \Evernote\Client::SORT_ORDER_REVERSE | \Evernote\Client::SORT_ORDER_RECENTLY_CREATED;

$results = $client->findNotesWithSearch($search, $notebook, $scope, $order, 20);
```

It works, but if I try get notes from linked notebooks, it get empty result all time.

Tried implement this - `https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/sharing.php`

```
$adClient = new \Evernote\AdvancedClient($token ,false);

$store = $adClient->getSharedNoteStore('linked_notbook_id');

$client = new \Evernote\Client($store->getToken(), false);

$search = new \Evernote\Model\Search('*');

$notebook = $carrier->getLinkedNotebooks()[0];

$scope = \Evernote\Client::SEARCH_SCOPE_ALL;

$order = \Evernote\Client::SORT_ORDER_REVERSE | \Evernote\Client::SORT_ORDER_RECENTLY_CREATED;

$results = $client->findNotesWithSearch($search, $notebook, $scope, $order, 20);
```

The same, empty result.

Answer (score 0):

Where did this `$carrier` come from?

```
$notebook = $carrier->getLinkedNotebooks()[0];
```

Assuming it's `$client`, LinkedNotebook from the SharedNoteStore is assigned to `$notebook` and it is passed to `findNotesWithSearch`, which doesn't seem right.

1. The LinkedNotebook object is for the user who is shared a notebook with. So calling that API with SharedNoteStore is probably not what you want. See https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/sharing.php
2. The type of second argument of `findNotesWithSearch` is `Notebook`. notebookGuid can be found in [SharedNotebook](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Types.html#Struct_SharedNotebook).